# System.Numerics.Vectors.Vector<T> is missing

Tags: c#, .net, vector, sse, .net-4.6

I'm studying examples of SIMD operations in C# and want to try some exapmles. I downloaded NuGet package `System.Numerics.Vectors v4.0`, and want to reproduce examples from the internet. But they doesn't work because this library doesn't contain class needed. Target framework is 4.6, but there is no `Vector<T>` for some reason, and I don't know why.

[image]

Maybe it was removed from API, but i didn't found any correlated info why they did it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect you installed the latest stable package from NuGet which doesn't include `Vector<T>`. Try installing the beta version (1.1.6-beta).

Comment: Note that the [release notes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/p/simd.aspx) for the NuGet package say that `Vector<T>` was removed from the stable release (presumably it wasn't stable enough)

Comment: Note that now it is distributed as NuGet package, but is not present in System.Numerics.Vectors preinstalled with.Net 4.6.